# print matrix in dialog box

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm having a little difficulty to print a matrix array on dialog box.
The matrix is integer and as far as i understood i need to change it into string?

anyway, here's the code:

```
    public void print_Matrix(int row, int column)
 {

  for (int i = 0; i <= row; i++)


  {
   for (int j = 0; j <= column; j++)
   {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, matrix_Of_Life);
   }
  }
```

what I need to do in order to print array into dialog box?

thanks.

Comment: What does matrix_Of_Life look like? Is it a multidimensional array?

Comment: public void set_Matrix(int row, int column)
 {
  matrix_Of_Life = new int [row][column];
    
  Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  for (int i = 0; i <= row-1; ++i)
  {
   for (int j = 0; j <= column-1; ++j)
   {
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(2);   //for random result "0" or "1"
       System.out.println("Generated : " + randomInt); 
   }   
  }
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For small 2D arrays, something like this is convenient:

```
int[][] matrix = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
String s = Arrays.deepToString(matrix)
   .replace("], ", "\n").replaceAll(",|\\[|\\]", "");

System.out.println(s);
```

This prints:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

This concedes control and speed for clarity and conciseness. If your matrix is larger and/or you want complete control on how each element is printed (e.g. right alignment), you'd probably have to do something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void printMatrix(char[][] mat) {

    StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();

    for(int i=0;i<mat.length;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<mat[0].length;j++){

            str.append(mat[i][j]).append(" ");
        }

        str.append("\n");
    }

    System.out.println(str.toString());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuffer str=new StringBuffer();

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{    
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        str.append(matrix[i][j]).str(" ");
    }
    str.append("\n");
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Matrix:"+"\n" +str);
```